# Unable to parse json using alamofire using closures

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

Currently learning Swift and I'm new to parsing of json.
I'm trying to parse json using alamofire using swift 3. However Im not getting any response. How should I get the value of parameter1 or parameter 2 which were nested?
My json looks like this:

```
{  "data":{  
  "level1":{  
     "level2":{  
        "parameter1":"000000",
        "parameter2":"00/00/00 00:00:00",
        "parameter3":"00.0",
     }
```

My swift code looks like this ,

```
func downloadDataDetails(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    //Get data from URL
    Alamofire.request("MY_URL").responseJSON { response in
        let result = response.result

        if let dict = result.value as? Dictionary<String , AnyObject> {
            if let data = dict["data"] as? String {
                if let level1 = dict["level1"] as? String {
                    if let level2 = dict["level2"] as? String? {
                        self._myValue = level2
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        completed()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you that use SwiftJson (https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftyJSON)

if you need to validate that something exist you can use .exist() (Return a boolean)

```
func test() {
        let json: JSON = [   "data":[
            "level1":[
                "level2":[
                    "parameter1":"000000",
                    "parameter2":"00/00/00 00:00:00",
                    "parameter3":"00.0"
                ]
            ]
            ]
            ]
            print(json) //Create a breakpoint here
    }
```

If you have this JSON and you need to know if parameter1 exist:

(Put a break point in print(json))

(In the Console)
(lldb) `po json["data"]["level1"]["level2"]["parameter1"].exists()
// response true`

In the code would be:

```
if json["data"]["level1"]["level2"]["parameter1"].exists(){

        }
```

If you need to get the value would be:

```
if json["data"]["level1"]["level2"]["parameter1"].exists(){

            let parameter1 = json["data"]["level1"]["level2"]["parameter1"]
            print(parameter1)
        }
```

Complete example:

```
func test() {
        let json: JSON = [   "data":[
            "level1":[
                "level2":[
                    "parameter1":"000000",
                    "parameter2":"00/00/00 00:00:00",
                    "parameter3":"00.0"
                ]
            ]
            ]
            ]
        if json["data"]["level1"]["level2"]["parameter1"].exists(){

            let parameter1 = json["data"]["level1"]["level2"]["parameter1"]
            print(parameter1)
        }
            print(json["parameter1"])
    }
```

The console log is:

```
000000
{
  "data" : {
    "level1" : {
      "level2" : {
        "parameter1" : "000000",
        "parameter3" : "00.0",
        "parameter2" : "00\/00\/00 00:00:00"
      }
    }
  }
}
```